# How to tell Java that a variable cannot possibly be null?

Tags: java, null, initialization

I have a program that basically looks like this:

```
boolean[] stuffNThings;
int state=1;
for(String string:list){
   switch(state){
      case 1:
         if(/*condition*/){
            // foo
            break;
         }else{
            stuffNThings=new boolean[/*size*/];
            state=2;
         }
      // intentional fallthrough
      case 2:
         // bar
         stuffNThings[0]=true;
   }
}
```

As you, a human, can see, case 2 only ever happens when there was previously a state 1 and it switched to state 2 after initialising the array. But Eclipse and the Java compiler don't see this, because it looks like pretty complex logic to them. So Eclipse complains:

> The local variable stuffNThings may not have been initialized."

And if I change "`boolean[] stuffNThings;`" to "`boolean[] stuffNThings=null;`", it switches to this error message:

> Potential null pointer access: The variable stuffNThings may be null at this location.

I also can't initialise it at the top, because the size of the array is only determined after the final loop in state 1.

Java thinks that the array could be null there, but I know that it can't. Is there some way to tell Java this? Or am I definitely forced to put a useless `null` check around it? Adding that makes the code harder to understand, because it looks like there may be a case where the value doesn't actually get set to `true`.

Comment: `Potential null pointer access: The variable stuffNThings may be null at this location.` - is that a warning or an error? It shouldn't be an error, so you can ignore it.

Comment: That code looks overly complex and the intention is not clear.  What is it meant to do?

Comment: @Eran Eclipse gives me an error, but when I click "Proceed", the program actually runs normally. Fascinating.

Comment: Where else do you use `stuffNThings`? In the loop, after the loop. My (uninformed) guess is that the code could look more readable. Maybe something for the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum.

Comment: @SteveSmith The real code codes through a file and first makes a list of things based on the first part of the file and then a 2D array of which of the entries have something to do with which other ones based on the lower part of the list. So in state 1 it adds to the list and then uses the size of the list to initialise the 2D array before going to state 2 and marking the correlations.

Comment: @JoopEggen It's used in the loop if "state" is 2, then after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After just trying to execute the code regardless of Eclipse complaining, I noticed that it does indeed run without problems. So apparently it was just a warning being set to "error" level, despite not being critical.
There was a "configure problem severity" button, so I set the severity of "Potential null pointer access" to "warning" (and adjusted some other levels accordingly). Now Eclipse just marks it as warning and executes the code without complaining.

Answer (score 5):

> Java thinks that the array could be null there, but I know that it can't.

Strictly speaking, Java thinks that the variable could be *uninitialized*.  If it is not definitely initialized, the value should not be *observable*.

(Whether the variable is silently initialized to `null` or left in an *indeterminate* state is an implementation detail.  The point is, the language says you shouldn't be allowed to see the value.)

But anyway, the solution is to initialize it to `null`.  It is redundant, but there is no way to tell Java to "just trust me, it will be initialized".

---

In the variations where you are getting "Potential null pointer access" messages:

1. It is a warning, not an error.
2. You can ignore or suppress a warning.  (If your correctness analysis is wrong then you may get NPE's as a result.  But that's your choice.)
3. You can turn off some or all warnings with compiler switches.
4. You can suppress a specific warning with a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation:

   - For Eclipse, use `@SuppressWarnings("null")`.
   - For Android, use `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")`.

     Unfortunately, the warning tags are not fully standardized.  However, a compiler should silently ignore a `@SuppressWarnings` for a warning tag that it doesn't recognize.
5. You may be able to restructure the code.

In your example, the code is using switch drop through.  People seldom do that because it leads to code that is hard to understand. So, I'm not surprised that you can find edge-case examples involving drop-through where a compiler gets the NPE warnings a bit wrong.

Either way, you can easily avoid the need to do drop-through by restructuring your code.  Copy the code in the `case 2:` case to the end of the `case 1:` case.  Fixed.  Move on.

---

Note the "possibly uninitialized" error is not the Java compiler being "stupid".  There is a whole chapter of the JLS on the rules for *definite assignment*, etcetera.  A Java compiler is not permitted to be smart about it, because that would mean that the same Java code would be legal or not legal, depending on the compiler implementation.  That would be bad for code portability.

What we actually have here is a language *design compromise*.  The language stops you from using variables that are (really) not initialized.  But to do this, the "dumb" compiler must sometimes stop you using variables that you (the smart programmer) know will be initialized ... because the rules say that it should.

(The alternatives are worse: either no compile-time checks for uninitialized variables leading to hard crashes in unpredictable places, or checks that are different for different compilers.)

Answer (score 0):

A distinct non-answer: when code is "so" complicated that an IDE / java compiler doesn't "see it", then that is a good indication that your code is *too complicated* anyway. At least for me, it wasn't obvious what you said. I had to read up and down repeatedly to convince myself that the statement given in the question is correct.

You have an if in a switch in a for. Clean code, and "single layer of abstraction" would tell you: not a good starting point.

Look at your code. What you have there is a *state machine* in disguise. Ask yourself whether it would be worth to refactor this on larger scale, for example by turning it into an *explicit* state machine of some sort.

Another less intrusive idea: use a List instead of an array. Then you can simply create an empty list, and **add** elements to that as needed.

Comment: I could of course loop over the file twice and abort after the first encounter of something that triggers state 2 in my example. But then I would have to read the beginning of the file twice, which is bad for performance. The list might work, but for now I'll try it with the 2D array, after applying the solution from my self-answer.

Comment: @FabianRöling That is not what I am saying! I am saying that you implement a state machine, and that OOP knows better ways to implement state machines than switch statements within loops.

Comment: After Friday 14:00 UTC I can give you the code and task, if you want to look at it and tell me if you know a better solution (I currently don't know any), for now it's forbidden, because that's my final exam.

Comment: @FabianRöling Keep in mind that this community isn't solely about solving *your* problem. It is about creating content that is helpful for future readers. And my answer to future readers is this: when you need a statemachine, then implement a state machine, instead of using ifs in switches in fors.

Answer (score 0):

More understandable would be:

```
    boolean[] stuffNThings;
    boolean initialized = false;
    for (String string: list) {
        if (!initialized) {
            if (!/*condition*/) {
                stuffNThings = new boolean[/*size*/];
                initailized = true;
            }
        }
        if (initialized) {
            // bar
            stuffNThings[0] = true;
        }
    }
```

Two loops, one for the initialisation, and one for playing with the stuff might or might not be more clear.

It is easier on flow analysis (compared to a switch with fall-through).

Furthermore instead of a `boolean[]` a `BitSet` might used too (as it is not fixed sized as an array).

```
BitSet stuffNThings = new BitSet(/*max size*/);
```

Comment: Wouldn't Eclipse complain about the same "might not have been initialised" thing in this version?